# Opencart: Adding Buy Now Button in Opencart Product Page

Tags: php, opencart

I was adding a Buy Now button in opencart product page (also add to cart will be there)

First i edited catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/product/product.tpl (to get Buy Now button in product page)

```
<?php if ($stock == "In Stock") { echo '<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" id="button-cart" class="button-product-page" />'; echo " "; echo '<input type="button" value="Buy Now" id="button-cart-buy" class="button-product-page" />'; } else {echo '<input type="button" value="Out Of Stock" class="button-product-page"/>'; } ?>
```

And after this,in product.tpl, i made a new function (button-cart-buy) for Buy Now similar to button-cart function but i changed the json['success'] as below for Buy Now:

```
if (json['success']) {window.location='index.php?route=checkout/checkout'; }
```

Its working when we click Buy Now on product page with link as (http://domain.com/Product) but its not working if we click Buy now after browsing product from categories i.e http://domain.com/MainCategory/SubCategory/Product then i am getting url as http://domain.com/MainCategory/SubCategory/index.php?route=checkout/checkout. But the product is getting added to the Cart.

This issue is mainly in IE and sometimes it occurs in Mozilla also.

I had also tried copying addtoCart function in common.js. But still not working out.

Am i missing something or need to alter..? Please help

**A word for thanks for Jay Gilford:**

Thanks Jay Gilford for your response.

This answer helps in resolving 5-6 open threads at opencart forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you're not using an absolute URL path. If this is in the template you've got this Javascript, you can just use

```
if (json['success']) {window.location='<?php echo $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL'); ?>'; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do i need to make any change in common.js also? or just making the above change in the template's product.tpl button-cart-buy function (i created) will do the required?

Comment: If this code is in the tpl file, you don't need to change the `common.js` file

Comment: Thanks a lot, this thread helps many open threads at opencart forum and will help many users. I have also edited the answer to have word of thanks