# How to empty basket before adding a product - Open Cart

Tags: opencart

Following this link:
[Opencart: Adding Buy Now Button in Opencart Product Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219679/opencart-adding-buy-now-button-in-opencart-product-page)

I added the following script on my page:

```js
 $('#button-cart-buy').bind('click', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(json) {
                        $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

                        if (json['error']) {
                            if (json['error']['option']) {
                                for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                                    $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                                }
                            }

                            if (json['error']['profile']) {
                                $('select[name="profile_id"]').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['profile'] + '</span>');
                            }
                        } 

                        if (json['success']) {window.location='<?php echo $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL'); ?>'; 
                        }

                    }
                });
            });
```

However, I would like to empty the cart before adding the product in question.

Does anyone know how to do it or have any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to edit the cart class `/system/library/cart.php`

Find this line (from a 1.5.5.1 install - any other version may vary slightly though unlikely to be majorly different)

```
public function add($product_id, $qty = 1, $option = array()) {
```

On a new line after it, add

```
$this->cart->clear();
```

And save. Note that this allows for a customer to add a quantity greater than 1 to a cart as long as it is the same product

Comment: I guess it will never allow user to add more than one item (of different type) even if they are using `add to cart` and not `buy now`. i guess better thing would be pass a variable indicating request came from `buy now button` with ajax and then in `controller/checkout/cart/add` if the `$_POST['buy_now']` exists then do a `$this->cart->clear();`.  also in library cart.php i guess it should `$this->clear();`

Comment: @ChetanPaliwal - That's correct. This is a quick and dirty method to do what the OP wants without much effort. Doing what you have suggested would require quite a bit of work

Comment: @ChetanPaliwal Please, add the correct answer as well. It would be nice to have it here since somebody else may search for same/similar solution. After it is done, reply to my comment so that I am notified and can upvote the correct approach.